# Matching Rapidshare links with regex

Tags: php, regex, rapidshare

I want to match a sequence of Rapidshare links on a webpage. The links look like:

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/326251387/file_name.rar
```

I wrote this code:

```
if(preg_match_all('/http:\/\/\rapidshare\.com\/files\/.*?\/.*?/', $links[1], $links))
{
    echo 'Found links.';
} else {
    die('Cannot find links :(');
}
```

And it retuns `Cannot find links :(` every time. Please note that I want to return the *entire* match, so it will bring back every Rapidshare link found on the page in an array.

`$links[1]` does have a valid string, too.

Any help will be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a stray backslash before rapidshare

```
if(preg_match_all('/http:\/\/\rapidshare\.com\/files\/.*?\/.*?/', $links[1], $links))
```

Should be

```
if(preg_match_all('/http:\/\/rapidshare\.com\/files\/.*?\/[^\s"']+/', $links[1], $links))
```

(`\r` is a carriage return character)

Comment: Thanks, stupid typos :) Just one thing though, now it retusn an array with links like: `http://rapidshare.com/files/328807106/`, eg not the filename too?

Comment: That only returns the first character, but thanks. Got it working :)

Comment: Updated it to match the filenames at the end. It'll stop when it sees whitespace, a " or ' character (assuming you're trying to pull data out of something like an href attribute...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of nonlogic HTTPS links to rapidshare.com, you can find them on google:
"https://rapidshare.com/files/"

I recommend changing your regex to include `https?:`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that madness you're getting into escaping slashes in URLs, I would use another [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for my regex -- like `#` for instance ; and this would help seeing that you have one too many `\` before `rapideshare`.

Then, you could have something that looks like this :

*(Inspired from yours -- only changed a bit at the end because it wasn't returning the file's name ;; you might want to adapt this a bit more, though, to exlclude some other characters than just white-spaces, like `"`)*

```
$str = 'blah http://rapidshare.com/files/326251387/file_name.rar blah';
if(preg_match_all('#http://rapidshare\.com/files/(.*?)/([^\s]+)#', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Which, here, will get you :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'http://rapidshare.com/files/326251387/file_name.rar' (length=51)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '326251387' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string 'file_name.rar' (length=13)
```